# Parsing calculation tree from string

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-construction

I there any built in library in c# or automatic code generator which recieves configuration file and builds parser of calculaton tree from string if there is no could you please help me with advice
Example:
"-2+5>3" I would like to build calculation tree where < is root '+' is its right son 3 is left son '-2' is left son of the + and 5 is its right son.
And the tree could do evaluation in this case true or false.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the System.Linq.Expressions? for example [How to convert string into System.Linq.Expressions.Expression in C#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/csharplanguage/thread/31ac96da-415e-424b-9e1f-6aec86c4c3ae)

Comment: Great solution , from different point of view you just let the c# compiler to do the parsing!!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [sprache](http://code.google.com/p/sprache/).  It's a simple parser which would allow you to build the expression tree and then evaluating it should be the easy bit.

Answer (score 3):

The [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) library is very simple to use, and comes with an expressions parser in the examples.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is evaluating the expression and not the tree itself - you can look at this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sota_expression_evaluator.aspx

It's probably worth noting, that the implementation of most expression evaluators is using RPN.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation